# Dynamic clear form Validation not Working inside FormGroup of FormArray angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to clear my validation for that particular group based on user input.I have tried like this but not work for me.

```
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      questions: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          question_name: ['', Validators.required],
          type: ['', Validators.required],
          point: ['', Validators.required],
          no_of_answer: [''],
          option: this.fb.array([]),
          right_answer: ['', Validators.required],
        }),
      ]),
    });

  this.type = [
      { name: 'Multiple choice choose one( radio)', type: 'radio' },
      { name: 'Multiple choice choose many', type: 'checkbox' },
      { name: 'True / False(radio)', type: 'radio' },
      {
        name: 'Fill in the blank single input',
        type: 'singleInput',
      },
      {
        name: 'Fill in the blank multiple choice',
        type: 'multipleInput',
      },
    ];

 // when question type is selected
  type_selected(comp) {
    const value = comp.get('type').value;
    switch (value) {
      case 'radio':
        const control = comp.controls['right_answer'] as FormControl;
        control.clearValidators();
        break;
      case 'checkbox':
        console.log('option required');
        break;
      case 'singleInput':
        console.log('Answer Required');
        break;
      case 'multipleInput':
        console.log('Multiple Answer Required');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('');
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div *ngIf="new_created; else existing">
        <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
          <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="create_company_fun()">
            <ng-container formArrayName="questions">
              <div
                class="row"
                *ngFor="let comp of questionFormArr.controls; let i = index"
              >
                <p-divider align="center" class="mt-3">
                  <div class="p-d-inline-flex p-ai-center">
                    <i class="pi pi-question p-mr-2"></i>
                    <b>Question {{ i + 1 }} </b>
                  </div>
                </p-divider>
                <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mt-5">
                    <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="inputtext"
                        class="form-control"
                        pInputText
                        formControlName="question_name"
                      />
                      <label for="inputtext">Question Name</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mt-5 d-flex">
                    <div>
                      <button
                        pButton
                        pRipple
                        type="button"
                        icon="pi pi-plus"
                        (click)="addNewQuestion()"
                        class="p-button-rounded p-button-success"
                      ></button>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-left: 1rem">
                      <button
                        pButton
                        pRipple
                        type="button"
                        icon="pi pi-minus"
                        (click)="deleteQuestion(i)"
                        class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger"
                      ></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
                    <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="inputtext"
                        class="form-control"
                        pInputText
                        formControlName="point"
                      />
                      <label for="inputtext">Points</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
                    <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                      <p-dropdown
                        inputId="dropdown"
                        [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
                        [options]="type"
                        [style]="{ minWidth: '100%' }"
                        optionLabel="name"
                        optionValue="type"
                        formControlName="type"
                        (onChange)="type_selected(comp)"
                      ></p-dropdown>
                      <label for="dropdown">Type</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-5"
                    *ngIf="comp.get('type').value == 'multipleInput'"
                  >
                    <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="inputtext"
                        class="form-control"
                        pInputText
                        formControlName="no_of_answer"
                      />
                      <label for="inputtext">Number of Answer</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <ng-container
                    *ngIf="
                      comp.get('type').value == 'radio' ||
                      comp.get('type').value == 'checkbox'
                    "
                  >
                    <div class="col-12" formArrayName="option">
                      <div
                        class="row"
                        *ngFor="
                          let project of comp.get('option')['controls'];
                          let j = index
                        "
                      >
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mt-5">
                          <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="inputtext"
                              class="form-control"
                              pInputText
                              [formControlName]="j"
                            />
                            <label for="inputtext">Option {{ j + 1 }} </label>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mt-5 d-flex">
                          <div>
                            <button
                              pButton
                              pRipple
                              type="button"
                              icon="pi pi-plus"
                              (click)="addNewOption(comp.get('option'))"
                              class="p-button-rounded p-button-success"
                            ></button>
                          </div>

                          <div style="margin-left: 1rem">
                            <button
                              pButton
                              pRipple
                              type="button"
                              icon="pi pi-minus"
                              (click)="deleteOption(comp.get('option'), j)"
                              class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger"
                            ></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ng-container>

                  <div
                    class="col-12 col-md-9 mt-5"
                    *ngIf="comp.get('type').value !== 'multipleInput'"
                  >
                    <span class="p-float-label w-100">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="inputtext"
                        class="form-control"
                        pInputText
                        formControlName="right_answer"
                      />
                      <label for="inputtext">Right Answer</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mt-5">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
                      Create
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </ng-container>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ng-template #existing>
        <app-add-from-existing-question></app-add-from-existing-question>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
```

What I want is, If the user selected single-input I want to hide options and their validation.

All Works fine except validation. I'm unable to clear or set validation inside my formgroup

Comment: I guess I have an answer to it. Request you to please add a `StackBlitz` for faster assistance.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bwu32j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.Before that I haven't used stackbliz

Comment: So you're trying to clear validations by using control.clearValidators()? inside your switch/case statement

Comment: Try calling `updateValueAndValidity` on control once you did  `control.clearValidators();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the `StackBlitz` link, however, the details are incomplete there and is throwing an error. Please update the link for future purposes.

Straight from the docs, please try using `updateValueAndValidity()` which recalculates the value and validation status of the control. Call it on your `control` constant variable as- `control.updateValueAndValidity();`

Link: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity